# jQuery UI Datepicker on ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How do you implement the jQuery UI Datepicker validation when working in ASP.NET web form? The base for this validation is from this site: http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html 
The problem I have is with the rule. Example:

```
$('#validateForm').validate({ 
errorPlacement: $.datepicker.errorPlacement, 
rules: { 
    txtDatepicker: { 
        required: true, 
        dpDate: true 
    }, 
}, 
messages: { 
    txtDatepicker: 'Please enter a valid date (yyyy-mm-dd)', 
}});
```

The "txtDatepicker" is the ASP:TextBox ID which changes when the page is rendered.  How do I specify this in the above rule syntax?  I tried to use property name="txtDatepicker" but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Id="txtDatepicker" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Just change the ClientID Mode, then the ID on the client will always be `txtDatepicker`.

Comment: Mason, when I added the ClientIDMode="Static" now I am getting error "unable to get property 'settings' of the undefined or null reference.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Check your JavaScript from the client side and make sure it matches what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Could do it like

```
$('#validateForm').validate({ 
errorPlacement: $.datepicker.errorPlacement, 
rules: { 
    <%=txtDatepicker.ClientID %>: { 
        required: true, 
        dpDate: true 
    }, 
}, 
messages: { 
    <%=txtDatepicker.ClientID %>: 'Please enter a valid date (yyyy-mm-dd)', 
}});
```

Comment: Mohamed, Your syntax does not work either.  Visual studio shows squiggly red line under the colon which is right after the <%=txtDatePicker.ClientID %>  What I tried also is to enclose the <% %> into double quotes. This removed the squiggly line but makes no difference in how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found that works (but for the life of me I don't understand why and how).

I have changed the rule as following:

```
$('#validateForm').validate({ 
 errorPlacement: $.datepicker.errorPlacement, 
rules: { 
  anystringorname: { 
  }, 
 }, 
 messages: { 
 }});
```

And then I add the class dpDate to my asp:textbox and everything works. That is, if I type in some bogus number (e.g. 12344) and click on Submit the focus is set to the asp:textbox and datepicker calendar appears. And if I type the valid date, the Submit works.  So everything works but note that the code above has a bogus name in the rules and no actual rules.  Yet if I comment the validate() all together, no validation takes place. And when typing a bogus number the Submit does not stop.  If anybody see what I don't see, please let me know.